# Whats the connection to Bart Simpson?

Tags: tmnt-secret-of-the-ooze

In [Ninja Turtles 2 (1991)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0103060/?ref_=fn_al_tt_2) when the TGRI professor and the turtles are making the antidote for Tokka and Rahzar, he turns to the camera, twice with the antidote in a glass that has Bart Simpson on it. It was pretty prominent so I have to ask, what's the connection there?

Comment: Er, they both say Cowabunga? ;) Doubt there are any subtleties in TMNT2, so maybe it's just because of 20th Century Fox (produces The Simpsons and distributed TMNT2).

Answer (score 3):

Fox, which produces *The Simpsons*, had the most lucritive distribution deal for TMNT2, and they decided to give a little "mini-shout" out to them.  Fox had the following deals:

- 20th Century Fox (1991) (France) (theatrical)
- 20th Century Fox (1991) (UK) (theatrical)
- 20th Century Fox of Germany (Germany) (theatrical) (1991)
- Fox Video (1992) (Germany) (VHS)
- Fox Network (1993) (USA) (TV) (broadcast premiere)
- 20th Century Fox Home Entertainment Japan (1993) (Japan) (VHS)
- Twentieth Century Fox Home Entertainment (Netherlands) (VHS)
- 20th Century Fox Home Entertainment (Brazil) (DVD)
- Twentieth Century Fox Home Entertainment (2002) (Netherlands) (DVD)
- 20th Century Fox Home Entertainment (2003) (Germany) (DVD)

Comment: Since *Fox* also produces *The Simpsons*, I guess?

Comment: You are correct, Sonny Jim...